# How to edit AssemblyInfo using Mono.Cecil/dnlib?

Tags: vb.net, mono.cecil, dnlib

As the question states, how do I edit assembly information of a compiled executable file using Mono.Cecil? 
I tried to use FileVersionInfo but it is Read Only and I came to know that there is a possibility with Mono.Cecil/dnlib.

Comment: This site is not for tutorials. There are tons of posts if you search.

Answer (score 0):

I am aware that the question is already a few months old, however, I post my answer anyways, maybe someone can profit from it in the future.

First of, dnlib/Mono.Cecil doesnt't yet have an inbuilt feature to modify the AssembyInfo of
a .NET executable file or a DLL.

However I can recommend you to use [resourcelib](https://github.com/dblock/resourcelib) from Daniel Doubrovkine.

It was exactly created for this purpouse.
Here is an example of how to use it:

```
VersionResource versionResource = new VersionResource();
versionResource.LoadFrom("C:\\MyFile.exe");

StringFileInfo stringFileInfo = (StringFileInfo)versionResource["StringFileInfo"];

versionResource["StringFileInfo"];
stringFileInfo["CompanyName"] = "My Company";
stringFileInfo["FileDescription"] = "This is a file";
stringFileInfo["ProductName"] = "My awesome product";
stringFileInfo["LegalCopyright"] = "Copyright Me";
```

You can save your changes like this :

```
versionResource.SaveTo("C:\\MyFile-patched.exe");
```